# Concentration during games

Tags: psychology

I've noticed that I lose sight of pieces' positions very fast during games, also, for some reason, I fail at having an "objective" view, some kind of an eagle eye, i.e I find myself concentrated on where the action is, the 3 or 4 squares related to the last move, this is obviously a default in me and would really wish to get helpful advice from you lots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I am the best person to answer this question as I have come across a similar kind of situation.

I would suggest you to first focus on whether you are losing your pieces by any opponent's strategy. Don't directly play with a high level opponent . For increasing your alertness, you can play chess on computer at a lower level and then gradually increase it once you start winning. 'Chess titans', for example, on Windows 7 is an excellent game to improve firstly your alertness, then the logical skills , and finally patience. Try to analyze what is happening on the board instead of narrowing your vision to 3-4 squares. This will greatly benefit you, my friend.

Now, we turn to logical skills. The most important thing here is to predict your opponent's move and develop your strategy to make him/her fall into your trap. Try to think simple rather than complicating situations. I would also suggest you to be calculative while playing. Here I mean to say that you should be able to think what is going to happen on the board after 2-3 moves. Thereafter, increase the count. I know that it is not possible in all situations, but try to exploit the situations where it works.

Finally,  patience. Patience , in any work, is the key to success. You can also calculate and plan your next moves while your opponent is planning his/her next move. Also you can try to be ahead of your opponent in calculations. For example , if your opponent has calculated what is going to happen in the next three moves, and if you have calculated upto 4 moves, then you have an edge over your opponent.

These simple techniques have helped me in overcoming my problems and I hope these will be beneficial for you too.

Comment: Bless you mon ami!

Comment: @archaic , it is my pleasure to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

The problems you're describing are common with inexperienced players, and that is only natural; the number of possible moves in the average chess position is rather large, and keeping track of everything that's going on in a position is basically impossible without guidelines and experience.

These problems (i.e. losing sight of the position of pieces/losing focus of everything except for a small region of the board) will gradually go away as you gain more experience. However there are things that you can do to actively speed up the process of improving your "eagle eye view" of a position, and the method I suggest is that you use the following checklist:

Each time you're on the move, look for

1. all the different checks available for you in the position;
2. all the different captures available for you in the position;
3. all the different checks that your opponent could make if it were their move;
4. all the different captures that your opponent could make if it were their move.

The reason for looking at these moves is that checks and captures are very forcing, and it will help you both see your own possibilities of scoring some easy points and it will also help you to find out what your opponent is threatening to do.

In the beginning this checklist will require some serious effort to complete for each move, but as you play more it will become easier to see the things mentioned in the checklist automatically without having to make a conscious effort.

Comment: Nice tips to be followed.